# Monitor two(2) serial ports at the same time asynchronously in Python

Tags: serial-port, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have two serial ports feeding data into Python. 
One is feeding GPS strings (about 4 lines per second)
and the other feeding data strings from a gas monitor (about 1 line every second)

I would like to monitor both gps and gas feeds at the same time and combine the data in realtime. I only need to receive data frpm the serial ports.

My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to get both python functions running at the same time.

I have the threading module and the multiprocessing module installed with Python 2.7.

Any ideas on a good way to combine serial info? This is my third Python program ever so please be gentle with me :-)

here's the code:

```
import threading
import multiprocessing

def readGas():
    global GAScount
    global GASline
    while GAScount<15:
        GASline = gas.readline()
        GasString = GASline.startswith('$')
        if GasString is True:
            print GASline
        GAScount = GAScount+1

def readGPS():
    global GPScount
    global GPSline
    while GPScount<50:
        GPSline = gps.readline()
        GPSstring = GPSline.startswith('$')
        if GPSstring is True:
            print GPSline
        GPScount = GPScount+1

openGPS()
openGas()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think threads would be a good choice in your case, as you don't expect very high frequencies. It will be much simpler than multiprocessing, because the memory remains shared between threads and you have less to worry.
The only remaining issue is that your acquisitions won't be exactly at the same time but rather one right after the other. If you really need synchronized data, you need to go with multiprocessing.

for threading :

```
import threading

# create your threads:
gps = threading.Thread(target=openGPS)
gas=threading.Thread(target=openGas)

#start your threads:
gps.start()
gas.start()
```

And you now have 2 acquisition thread running. Due to python's Global Interpret Lock, this is not properly at the same time but will alternate between the 2 threads.

more informations on threading : https://pymotw.com/2/threading/
more informations on GIL : https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: Thanks for that! and for the links :-)